Prove that $|\log |x||^p$ is not in $BMO(\mathbb{R})$ when $1 < p < \infty$.
I know that $f(x)=|\log|x||$ is in BMO (bounded mean oscillation). But how can we prove that $f(x)=|\log|x||^p$ for $1<p<\infty$ is not in BMO? I am trying using the John-Nirenberg inequality, but i don't know how to do, could anyone give me some hints?
